# How to change div backgroundcolor onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a div change backgroundcolor when clicking on another div.

Here is what i am trying:

`<script> document.getElementsByClassName("this").style.backgroundColor = "red"; </script>`
where the div has a class "this" assigned to it and the current backgroundcolor is black

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question. Please reconcile them.

Comment: mb. But can u answer the question to the title? i was going to ask that too but i have to wait.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list, not a single element, so you need to iterate over it and for each matching element, set the background color (or just use `.querySelector('.this')` to get a single element

```js
document.querySelector('.that').addEventListener('click', () => {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('this')).forEach((el) => {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
});
```

```css
.this { background-color: black; width: 100px; height: 100px }
```

```html
<div class="this">Target</div>
<div class="that">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to change the div color and after this add this function on a "onClick" attribute in the div that will be pressed like this:

```
<body>
  <div onclick="changeColor()"> Div that will be pressed </div>
  <div class="this" > Div that will change </div>
  <script>
        function changeColor() {
        var div = document.querySelector(".this");
        div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
  </script>
</body>
```